# Filter Nginx log in ELK by custom pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx, logging, filebeat, elk

I have installed ELasticsearch + Logstash + Kibana 7.11.0 using Docker on a ubuntu server. On this server I have Nginx with custom log format also installed Filebeat to tail logs and push to ELK.
No in Kibana dashboard -> Discover section I have all loges. On the right side, I see some filter fields. One of them is "message" with contain exact each log line content like this:

```
10.20.30.40 - [19/Feb/2021:18:10:49 +0000] "GET /blog/post/1 HTTP/2.0" - [sts: 200] "https://google.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; SM-N975F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.152 Mobile Safari/537.36" "-" "dns.com" rbs=103 sn=*.dns.com rt=0.002 uadd=127.0.0.1:3000 us=200 urt=0.000 url=103 rid=b694742bf2cca075d33bada95ce2c46f pck="cachekey-1010265" ucs=-
```

I have a custom GROK pattern for my log file and here is my logstash.conf content:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => 5044
    }

    tcp {
        port => 5000
    }
}

filter {
 grok {
   match => [ "message" , '%{IPORHOST:ip} (?:-|(%{WORD})) \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"(?:%{WORD:method} %{NOTSPACE:uri}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|-)\" - \[sts\: (?:%{WORD:response})\] \"%{NOTSPACE:referrer}\" \"%{DATA:http_user_agent}\" \"(?:-|())\" \"(?:%{NOTSPACE:hostname})\" rbs=(?:%{WORD:body_bytes_sent}) sn=(?:%{NOTSPACE:server_name}) rt=(?:%{NOTSPACE:request_time}) uadd=(?:%{IPORHOST:upstream_addr}):%{NUMBER:upstream_port} us=(?:%{NUMBER:upstream_status}) urt=(?:%{NOTSPACE:upstream_response_time}) url=(?:%{NUMBER:upstream_response_length}) rid=(?:%{WORD:request_id}) pck=(?:%{NOTSPACE:cache_key}) ucs=(?:%{NOTSPACE:upstream_cache_status})']
   overwrite => [ "message" ]
 }
 mutate {
   convert => ["response", "integer"]
   convert => ["bytes", "integer"]
   convert => ["responsetime", "float"]
 }
 geoip {
   source => "clientip"
   target => "geoip"
   add_tag => [ "nginx-geoip" ]
 }
 date {
   match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
   remove_field => [ "timestamp" ]
 }
 useragent {
   source => "agent"
 }
}
output {
 elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
   user => "elastic"
   password => "MY_PASS"
   index => "nginx-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
   document_type => "nginx_logs"
 }
 stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

My question is how can I use may GROP pattern on it? How can I filter my logs based on geoIP, or time duration or referral URL or other fields in my log? I did not understand it yet!

Here is filters section which I selected "message" field to show me the real log lines:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A few points based on your screenshot and the rest of the details you've provided :

1. Message field by default contains exactly the logline which is sent by the filebeat to the logstash and then to the index(nginx-* in your case)
2. Each log line gets stored in a separate event called a "document" with the above-mentioned message field as one of the fields.
3. For every log, you should be able to see the rest of the fields as you have parsed separately as the grok pattern you have applied here. If not, you will see the field "tags" with a value "_grokparsefailure" for that specific log-event/document. This means the grok pattern you tried to use to parse that logline is not appropriate as the logline has a different pattern than the grok pattern you applied for parsing.
4. Also, you might wanna check if you have created the index pattern with a time field as @timestamp or any other time field so that you can apply a range filter to see it on the basis of the time it occurred.

Happy log parsing :)